# What is going on with FIDE Federation "NON FEDERATION"?

Tags: fide, uscf

In the latest FIDE rating list the former USA players [Alejandro Ramirez](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/6500617) and [Timur Gareyev](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/14200937) have their federation listed as "NON FEDERATION". I understand they have both faced accusations of sexual misconduct but I'm puzzled as to how their federation changed from "USA" to "NON". Anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this document](https://new.uschess.org/sites/default/files/media/documents/member-disposition-spreadsheet.pdf) from the USCF, the USCF membership of both of these players has been permanently revoked by the Executive Board. Since they are no longer members of the USCF, they can't play under USA.